# ipad airplay mirroring to multiple airplay receivers (specifically for videos/pictures)

Tags: ipad, airplay

my client asks me to develop some app for real-estate presentation which has the following features:
1. The seller can have their ipads connect to the projector wireless over wifi.
2. The seller can broadcast the screenshot of some other ipads to the customers's ipads.

For feature 1, I can have a apple TV and airplay mirroring the ipad screen to it, then have some HDMI-VGA adapter for the connection with the projector.

For feature 2, I can also install airfloat to make the ipad an airplay receiver. I can also airplay mirroring the screen of the seller's ipad to the customer's ipad.

As for as I know, it seems to be no way to airplay mirroring the screenshot of one ipad to multiple ipad airplay receivers.

So I'm wondering how can I airplay mirroring one screen to many ipad airplay receivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you use airview or airplay receiver like in this link? It seen like we need to solve some problem to use.
https://github.com/nto/AirView

Another one is you can use this SDK. It has screen sharing and gesture sharing from one device to another device. It seen quite good.
http://www.showkit.com/

Answer (score 1):

Our rPlay airplay mirroring software implemented the features you asked. rPlay acts as Apple TV, you can mirror ios devices to it, rPlay can also duplicate displays to other rPlay devices, the result is one ios device sends its screens to multiple devices.

We are also develop viewers for mobile devices to receive rPlay displays.

Check our forums at http://www.vmlite.com for more info